# How do you access the request object inside django forms.py?

Tags: django, dynamic, django-forms

More specifically, I need to access the request object inside the **init** method of a form object. Here is my code:

```
class TagNamesField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):

        super (TagNamesField,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.required = True
        self.widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size' : 50, 'autocomplete' : 'off'})
        self.max_length = 255
        self.label  = _('tags')
        #self.help_text = _('please use space to separate tags (this enables autocomplete feature)')
        self.help_text = _('Tags are short keywords, with no spaces within. At least %(min)s and up to %(max)s tags can be used.') % {
            'min': settings.FORM_MIN_NUMBER_OF_TAGS, 'max': settings.FORM_MAX_NUMBER_OF_TAGS
        }
        self.initial = self.request.session['previous_url']
        self.user = user
```

Basically, I want to initialize this form: `self.initial = self.request.session['previous_url']`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms and widgets are decoupled from request informaton *by design*. Simple way to do what you want is to *instantiate a form* in a view this way:

```
form = SomeForm(initial={'tags': self.request.session['whatever']})
```

However, it might be more apropriate to create a *custom form* accepting `request` as an extra argument (giving form class acces to it):

```
form = SomeForm(request=request)
```